# Detecting recursion in a WSDL

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to import [this WSDL](https://api.cvent.com/soap/V200611.ASMX?WSDL) into a Logic App Custom connector, but Azure complains:

> “'The translation of the WSDL document to an Open API definition failed with error 'Element named 'xxx://api.cvent.com/2006-11:EventParameters' has a recursive definition. Recusive types are not supported.'.'. Status code: 'BadRequest'.”

This is a [known issue with Logic Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2018/01/26/recursive-types-declaration-in-wsdl-and-logic-apps-soap-custom-connector/).

It appears I need to remove the recursion (if possible). The problem is, I don't know how to *find* recursion in a WSDL.

Twofold question:

1) Given the WSDL linked above, where is the recursion?

2) How did you know where to look?

Thanks!

Comment: Your URL does not seem to return any content (client just waits for response from the server...) And the second one gives an error.

Comment: The first link, [this one](https://api.cvent.com/soap/V200611.ASMX?WSDL), works for me. I tested it on multiple connections. I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. The second link ('http://api.cvent.com/2006-11:EventParameters') is just SO helpfully highlighting the non-functional URL-link string Azure randomly threw into the error message. It's not valid. I'll edit out the http and it will probably go away.

Comment: Ok. I see your WSDL has 6267 lines... Your provider is not very nice by not giving you more details about what is happening. Especially since a quick look does not show a recursion in `EventParameters`...

Comment: It's possible there is no recursion. I'm just going on Azure's say-so, after all.

Comment: I will try another look later if I can. What you could try is to edit the WSDL on the EventParameters complexType definition by starting with a very simple definition, testing its acceptance and then slowly adding back more stuff to understand when it breaks to pinpoint the specific part. Tedious but a possible path. Basically a dichotomy/bisect search...

Comment: Try changing the type name too, the parser may get confused because the same name is both used as an element name and as a type name.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid this problem by not even bothering to import the WSDL.  Most of the time, doing so only automates the addition of 2-3 Headers and the Envelope.  For all the complications of SOAP, there isn't much to it :)

Then you still have to create the actual message on you own and including the Envelope is pretty trivial.  Meaning, it's nice the Custom Connector supports SOAP, but it doesn't get you very much, especially if you're only using 1 or two operations.

Basically, I would try with just the HTTP Connector first before working to get the WSDL and Custom Connector happy with each other:

[Using SOAP Services with Logic Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/04/07/using-soap-services-with-logic-apps/)

Comment: Good point. I actually had put together a brief POC using a plain HTTP connector to the service and it wasn't difficult to set up. In this case though, there are 51 routes and re-usability might be an issue. Still, it's worth considering.

Comment: It occurs to me that I might not have understood what you were suggesting. You were saying to use a naked HTTP request as part of a Logic App workflow, _without any custom connector are all_, right? Or is there a way to build a custom connector with SOAP envelopes, etc? Because I do like being able to use custom connectors as part of a Logic App.

Comment: @crowhill Yes, I suggesting a plain HTTP request will avoid your specific problem altogether.  SOAP is just a *pattern* for using Xml over primarily http, it's not anything special on its own.  Most of the time, the only thing SOAP adds for no real value unfortunately :( is the Envelope which is just some outer Xml elements.